# make tree in scheme

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, scheme, binary-tree

```
(define (entry tree) (car tree))
(define (left-branch tree) (cadr tree))
(define (right-branch tree) (caddr tree))
(define (make-tree entry left right) (list entry left right))

(define (mktree order items_list)
  (cond ((= (length items_list) 1)
         (make-tree (car items_list) '() '()))
        (else 
         (insert2 order (car items_list) (mktree order (cdr items_list))))))

(define (insert2 order x t)
  (cond ((null? t) (make-tree x '() '()))
      ((order x  (entry t))
       (make-tree (entry t) (insert2 order x (left-branch t)) (right-branch t)))
      ((order  (entry t) x )
       (make-tree (entry t) (left-branch t) (insert2 order x (right-branch t))))
      (else t)))
```

The result is:

```
(mktree (lambda (x y) (< x y)) (list 7 3 5 1 9 11))
(11 (9 (1 () (5 (3 () ()) (7 () ()))) ()) ())
```

But I'm trying to get:

```
(7 (3 (1 () ()) (5 () ())) (9 () (11 () ())))
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Updated your tag to scheme as I suppose that's what it is...

Comment: Is this Racket? (Formerly known as PLT Scheme.)

Comment: Looks like you need some much simpler test cases!

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

```
(define (mktree order lst)
  (let loop ((lst  lst)
             (tree '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        tree
        (loop (cdr lst) (insert order (car lst) tree)))))

(define (insert order ele tree)
  (cond ((null? tree)
         (make-tree ele '() '()))
        ((order ele (entry tree))
         (make-tree (entry tree)
                    (insert order ele (left-branch tree))
                    (right-branch tree)))
        ((order (entry tree) ele)
         (make-tree (entry tree)
                    (left-branch tree)
                    (insert order ele (right-branch tree))))
        (else tree)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(mktree < '(7 3 5 1 9 11)) 
> '(7 (3 (1 () ()) (5 () ())) (9 () (11 () ())))
```

Your `insert2` procedure is fine, but the `mktree` procedure should be expressed as an iteration over the list, with an accumulator keeping track of the tree with the elements inserted so far. This has two effects:

1. `mktree` is now tail-recursive and
2. Iteration order over the elements in the list is reversed

The last one in particular will fix your problem: even though your solution produces a binary tree, the order property is reversed w.r.t what you expected. Notice that reversing the input list will also work.

Comment: Oscar's right; the tree that you're getting right now also satisfies the binary tree invariants that you wanted.  But the tree has been constructed by considering the input in reverse order.  As John Clements suggests, you should try small test cases first to identify the problem.  To make the point clearer, consider a much smaller test input, such as '(2 1 3).

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Oscar Lopez is correct, yours due to the recursive nature of your
insert2 function call, it first gets the S-expression fully expanded and then starts the evaluation from the last 2 elements of the list (in your case 9 and 11)...
as a proof of this you can see that if you put in the list in the reversed order you get
the correct result:

`(mktree (lambda (x y) (< x y)) (list 11 9 1 5 3 7))`

`(7 (3 (1 () ()) (5 () ())) (9 () (11 () ())))`